# LINQ 2 lefts joins with Sum

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to do a relatively straight forward SQL query with linq:

```
SELECT ir.resource_id, r.first_name, r.surname, rt.job_title, SUM(plan_ts_hours), SUM(ts_hours) FROM tbl_initiative_resource ir
INNER JOIN tbl_resource r ON ir.resource_id = r.resource_id
INNER JOIN tbl_resource_type rt ON rt.resource_type_id = r.resource_type_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_plan_timesheet pts on pts.resource_id = ir.resource_id AND pts.initiative_id = ir.initiative_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_timesheet ts on ts.resource_id = ir.resource_id AND ts.initiative_id =     ir.initiative_id
WHERE ir.initiative_id = 111
GROUP BY ir.resource_id, r.first_name, r.surname, rt.job_title
```

After reading this blog: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/linq-how-to-build-complex-queries-utilizing-deferred-execution-and-anonymous-types/

I came up with the following linq:

```
var query = (from initRes in Context.tbl_initiative_resource
                     join res in Context.tbl_resource on initRes.resource_id equals res.resource_id
                     join resType in Context.tbl_resource_type on res.resource_type_id equals resType.resource_type_id
                     from tsheet in Context.tbl_timesheet.Where(x => x.resource_id == initRes.resource_id).Where(x => x.initiative_id == initRes.initiative_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     from plannedtsheet in Context.tbl_plan_timesheet.Where(x => x.resource_id == initRes.resource_id).Where(x => x.initiative_id == initRes.initiative_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where initRes.initiative_id == initiativeID
                     group new { ID = res.resource_id, ResourceType = resType.job_title, Times = tsheet, P = plannedtsheet } by initRes.resource_id into g
                     select new
                     {
                         ResourceID = g.Key,
                         Hours = g.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Times.ts_hours),
                         PlannedHours = g.Sum(x => (decimal?)x.P.plan_ts_hours)
                     }).ToList();
```

Any ideas on how I can access the ResourceType when selecting the new anonymous type?

Answer (score 0):

`ResourceType` is part of the the grouping key, so `g.Key.ResourceType` should do it.

(Check out the type of `ResouceID` in the results, as you've assigned it `g.Key` it will be an instance of the (anonymous) type created in the `group` clause.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, g.Key is of type int, not the anonymous type.